# Any tool for image to CSS?

Tags: css, images, tools, file-conversion

I have an image (not gradient) color, I tried to identify the color code but not possible. Is there any tool to convert image to css or css color code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need eyedropper kind of tool, for example:

- Open image in Adobe Photoshop/Fireworks and use Eyedropper tool
- [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/firefox/) extension for Firefox
- [Eye Dropper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka) extension for Google Chrome
- [EyeDropper](http://www.inetia.com/en/eyedropper/about-program/) standalone Windows application.
- [ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) for Windows

Answer (score 3):

Any graphics program like Photoshop or Gimp can tell you what the hex code or RGB that color is.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac: the built-in DigitalColor Meter.
On Windows: [ColorPic](http://iconico.com/colorpic/)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few online tools that will allow you to extract color palettes from a photo or other image.  You'll get an output of what the dominant colors are in the image (as there are millions of colors).
Try [ColorSuckr](http://colorsuckr.com/) and [CSS Drive Color Palette Generator](http://www.cssdrive.com/imagepalette/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you use IE8 & above, there is a [Color Picker](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2008/10/ie-developer-tools-tips-tricks-1.html) available with Developer Tools (F12 shortcut key) that you can use to identify the color code.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a program called Pendule for Chrome which has loads of webdev tools on it, including a color picker :).